# While printing xy coordinates of webelement using Selenium web-driver getting java.lang.NumberFormatException

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

Below is my sample code that take from this Stackoverflow question [Not able to drag element using Actions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50469971/not-able-to-drag-element-using-actions)

Sample code that used to find the webelement XY cordinates. By getting error "org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died."

Or in the error printed on the eclipse console getting "Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "617.7"

```
    WebDriver browser = new ChromeDriver();
browser.get("http://www.seleniumeasy.com/test/drag-and-drop-demo.html");

// Robot class uses Screen Coordinates, therefore, we need the fullscreen browser 
// instead of maximised. so that the webpage coordinates are mapped to screen
// coordinates.
browser.manage().window().fullscreen();

WebElement itemToBeDragged = browser
            .findElement(By.xpath(" (//h3[contains(.,'Items to Drag')]//following-sibling::span)[1]"));
WebElement whereToBeDragged = browser.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='mydropzone']"));

// robot class object to perform actual mouse events.
// import java.awt.Robot and java.awt.event.InputEvent
Robot robot = new Robot();

try {
         robot.mouseMove(itemToBeDragged.getLocation().x+(int)itemToBeDragged.getSize().width/2, itemToBeDragged.getLocation().y+(int)itemToBeDragged.getSize().getHeight()/2);
          Thread.sleep(1000);
          robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
          robot.mouseMove(itemToBeDragged.getLocation().x+(int)itemToBeDragged.getSize().width/3, itemToBeDragged.getLocation().y+(int)itemToBeDragged.getSize().getHeight()/3);
          Thread.sleep(1000);


          Thread.sleep(1000);
          robot.mouseMove(whereToBeDragged.getLocation().x+(int)whereToBeDragged.getSize().width/3, whereToBeDragged.getLocation().y+(int)whereToBeDragged.getSize().getHeight()/3);

          Thread.sleep(1000);
          robot.mouseMove(whereToBeDragged.getLocation().x+(int)whereToBeDragged.getSize().width/2, whereToBeDragged.getLocation().y+(int)whereToBeDragged.getSize().getHeight()/2);


        Thread.sleep(1000);
        robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK);

        Thread.sleep(1000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Below is my Error what i get in Eclipse Console.

```
FAILED: DragnDrop
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.53.0', revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 16:57:40'
System info: host: 'Assembly-SRV-India-01', ip: '192.168.56.1', os.name: 'Windows Server 2019', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '13.0.1'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
Capabilities [{mobileEmulationEnabled=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, hasTouchScreen=false, platform=XP, acceptSslCerts=false, goog:chromeOptions={debuggerAddress=localhost:53007}, acceptInsecureCerts=false, webStorageEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, setWindowRect=true, unexpectedAlertBehaviour=ignore, applicationCacheEnabled=false, rotatable=false, networkConnectionEnabled=false, chrome={chromedriverVersion=80.0.3987.106 (f68069574609230cf9b635cd784cfb1bf81bb53a-refs/branch-heads/3987@{#882}), userDataDir=C:\Users\ADMINI~1\AppData\Local\Temp\scoped_dir13692_615110410}, takesHeapSnapshot=true, pageLoadStrategy=normal, strictFileInteractability=false, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, version=80.0.3987.163, browserConnectionEnabled=false, proxy={}, nativeEvents=true, locationContextEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true}]
Session ID: 3fd2a3a2ac16566e351a75da0844a4d4
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:665)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.getLocation(RemoteWebElement.java:380)
    at login.onlinedraganddrop.DragnDrop(onlinedraganddrop.java:51)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
**Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "617.7"**
    at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
    at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:658)
    at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:535)
    at java.base/java.math.BigInteger.<init>(BigInteger.java:673)
    at com.google.gson.internal.LazilyParsedNumber.longValue(LazilyParsedNumber.java:51)
    at com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive.getAsLong(JsonPrimitive.java:233)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convertJsonPrimitive(JsonToBeanConverter.java:249)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:75)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convertMap(JsonToBeanConverter.java:344)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:219)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:144)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.JsonToBeanConverter.convert(JsonToBeanConverter.java:43)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.JsonHttpResponseCodec.decode(JsonHttpResponseCodec.java:78)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:644)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: @DipakBachhav No i am not using Selenium Grid

Answer (score 1):

`mouseMove()` method takes `integer` as the variable, however you are using the division method on the dimensions which would be returning a `double/float` value due to which you are getting `NumberFormatException`.
To resolve the issue, you need to typecast those values to `int`.

You can do it like:

```
robot.mouseMove(robot.mouseMove(itemToBeDragged.getLocation().x+(int)itemToBeDragged.getSize().width/2), itemToBeDragged.getLocation().y+(int)itemToBeDragged.getSize().getHeight()/2));
```

You need to append `(int)` before every value in which you are using a division method.

Comment: Hi  @Sameer Arora thanks for the Answer.
but i am still getting the same error, help me

Comment: @TomMartin did you make the changes in every line of code where its required?